# Moment JS Show Local Time from DateTime.UTCNow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, utc, momentjs

I have a JSON method which is returning a UTC DateTime I am storing on the server. It returns the following:

```
/Date(1394155885817)/
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get Moment JS to show me the local (browser) time. So my timezone is -5 (EST) I'd want to see 3:31 instead of 8:31. See the fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/R9UbS/

What am I doing wrong here? How can I force Moment to return local?

Comment: You could to `ToLocalTime` on the serverside.

Comment: Need client to take care of it. How would the server know the Client TimeZone

Comment: It doesn't but I don't think that Javascript knows it either. Can't you pass a proper dateTime object from the server to Javascript so JS knows which timezone it is offered?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the fiddle in Romania and got 3:31. Also, javascript's Date constructor handles UTC millis correctly. You're getting 8:31 which makes me think it's doing what it's supposed to do, showing the local time. Why is 8:31 incorrect? And is your device's timezone set correctly? (Btw if your timezone is GMT -5 then you would indeed get 8:31 PM the previous day)

Just to put this a bit in perspective, i put the number in a [milliseconds to time converter](http://www.currentmillis.com/) and i saw that 1394155885817 actually means Fri Mar 07 2014 1:31:25 AM in UTC (or GMT for convenience) - subtracting 5 hours from this would result in Fri Mar 06 2014 8:31:25 PM

Comment: Hi Teo thanks for the thoughts. So here is my scenario. I have my website hosted on Azure and in C# I'm saving the record with DateTime.UTCNow - For this particular case, when I created that record it was at 3:31 PM EST my time. However when the JSON was serialized and returned it was the /Date(1394155885817)/ stamp which is 5 hours ahead of the time I wanted. Which makes some sense since I'm in EST which is -5. Am I still thinking about this wrong?

Comment: 1394155885817 is 1:31 AM UTC so it's actually 10 hours ahead of 3:31 PM EST. Maybe there's something wrong with your serializing? (Can you post the exact code you're using to serialize?) To be complete, i *think* you should do this (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime (1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds

Comment: See Hath's answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290227/java-system-currenttimemillis-equivalent-in-c-sharp)