# Datetime to milliseconds in c#?

Tags: java, c#

I am trying to convert a sample java code to c#. This is the java code and I need some assistance in figuring out the proper way to get the equivalent code in c#. This is what I tried so far.

java code

```
TimeZone kenyaTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Kenya");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(kenyaTimeZone);
long timestamp = calendar.getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
```

C# code

```
TimeZoneInfo tzone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Africa /Kenya");
DateTimeOffset dt = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow, tzone.BaseUtcOffset);
```

This is where I am stuck. Please help me out. I would like to get the result in milliseconds and I am unable to figure out the proper way to do it.

Comment: what's wrong? what's the expected result?

Comment: What do you want the result to be?

Comment: @bornfromanegg:= I would like to know if I am doing it the right way and how i can convert the DateTimeOffset object to milliseconds.

Comment: Do you mean the number of milliseconds since the start of the day?

Comment: @bornfromanegg:- I am not sure about that as I am trying to figure out that from the java code.

Comment: Do you know that `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` returns the current time as UTC milliseconds from the epoch and therefore the TimeZone is a complete waste

Comment: @devpuh:- So, how should I go about it in my c# code?

Comment: See [Java System.currentTimeMillis() equivalent in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290227/java-system-currenttimemillis-equivalent-in-c-sharp)

Comment: A very similar question/answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955883/datetimes-representation-in-milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

To convert the difference between two datetimes to milliseconds:

```
double totalMs = (endDate - startDate).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this short code could help you. I read that java function "calendar.getTimeInMillis()" returns the milliseconds since 1970-01-01 (Like Unix Timestamp).

```
    var dt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. Africa Standard Time"));
    // Get C# time in milliseconds (since 1900-01-01)
    double milli = new TimeSpan(dt.Ticks).TotalMilliseconds;

    // Get Unix timestamp
    double unix = dt.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds;

    Console.WriteLine("Total Milliseconds: {0}  Unix: {1}", milli, unix);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
decimal miliseconds = myDateTime.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds;
```

> myDateTime is a DateTime object

good luck :)